# Perfect Bayesian Equilibrium for banks

Tags: banking, bayesian-game, principal-agent

I'm reading this paper on credit lending cycles and trying to understand how it works for the case of one bank. This is the set-up of the model: 
There are two players, a bank and the market. There are also two states of the world: adverse and normal.

The banks lends across time t=0,1 and 2. The bank can be of two types: High type, which generates profitable loans with a high probability $\theta$ in normal times and generates profitable loans with probability 0 in adverse times. Low type, which generates profitable loans with a probability lesser than $\theta$ in normal times and probability 0 in adverse times.

The bank lends loans in period 0 and becomes aware of the state of the world in period 1 when the loans turn out good or bad. If the loan is bad the bank can either terminate the loan with a cost of -1 dollars or can decide on a credit policy ( for eg extending the term of the bad loan). The credit policy varies between [0,a] and comes with a cost c in period 2 for the bank. After the credit policy is implemented the market observes the bank's earnings and updates its reputation, which is given by p+ = Prob( H/positive earnings in period1) and p- = Prob (H/negative earnings in period 1). Having implemented the credit policy, the bank's earnings can remain unaffected with probability a, and can become negative with probability 1-a.

Now in such a scenario, given the utility function of the manager as shown in equation (1) of the image attached, how do I formulate the incentive compatibility problem of the manager. I should reach equation(3) from the ICC, but I'm not able to at the moment on my own.

image of equ (1) and (3) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hlyi.jpg

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Economics SE! we have a policy regarding homework questions where we require that you show some work before an answer is provided. More on this topic here: https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions

Comment: Hi, thanks kitsune. This isnt a homework question, I'm doing some self-study as a part of research for my dissertation. I have arrived at an answer finally. However, I still would like to have an in-depth understanding of how BNE works when both states and types are unknown to the public. ( So far I had only studied cases where either the state or the type of the player is unknown ).